# Is there a force when electrically charged particles are around DC current?

Tags: esd, charge

Is there a force when electrically charged particles are around DC current?

I mean that if there are statically charged plastic particles in the switch, is it easy to move into the contact or not due to current?

Comment: An unvarying current only occurs in a conductor because there are surface charge gradiations to motivate it. These surface charges will interact with other static charges. However, in the classical interpretation an unvarying current does not produce a varying magnetic field and therefore cannot act as a secondary effect to also affect static charges.

Comment: While it is true that stationary charged particles feel no force due to a constant magnetic field, in the real world and in the case of an electrical switch, sooner or later the switch will be flipped off, the magnetic field surrounding the conductor will collapse. So a charged particle will feel a force in a changing magnetic field. Then there is the case where the switch is again closed producing a brief expanding magnetic field. With all that said the force would be quite small (assuming you’re not passing very high currents).

Comment: If there is force, will contact of switch attract the charged particles? Because, i can see plastic particle on the contact of switches(continuity failed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static currents only have static magnetic fields around them. These exert no force on static charges.

And to address what @jonk said: If the current flows through a resistive wire with non-zero resistance (i.e. *not* a superconducting wire), the wire will have a slightly different electric potential along its length. This creates a slight *electric* field also external to and along the length of the wire. This will indeed create a force on a static charge.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a force when electrically charged particles are around DC current?

As mentioned in another answer, the electric and magnetic fields associated with a constant current will be constant/static.

Constant magnetic fields do not produce forces on *stationary* charged particles. They *do* however produce forces on *moving* charged particles. This is called the Lorentz force, and it underlies the physics for Hall effect devices (which can sense static magnetic fields, and consequently, DC current.)

Constant electric fields cause forces on charged particles -- but not on the charged particles in nearby conductive bodies, at least not after a very brief time. The electrons in a conductive body in a constant electric field will rearrange themselves so that the density of charges on their surfaces is exactly what is required to cancel out any electric field in the interior of the conductive body. So although there is a static electric field associated with a constant current flowing through a resistive wire, that field doesn't penetrate into the interior of a nearby wire. The nearby wire is "shielded" by its own "Faraday cage".

Comment: How about this case. If DC voltage is applied between contacts(no current), electric field is induced. Is there any force to attract charged particle into the contacts? Because, i found many limit switches have some plastic particles that makes continuity failure on the contact

Answer (score 0):

I tested using plastic particles.
During switch off, I could see that charged particles moved into the contacts due to electric field of external power.
So, plastic particles from mold are very risky during operation.
Thanks.